# How could I recreate this psychedelic HDMI effect?

Tags: software-recommendation, effects

My new company laptop and my new gaming monitor do not go well together. On the other hand, this is some flashy psychedelic art ...

Is it possible to recreate such an effect, given a source image? If yes, with which software?

I don't know what exactly happened, of course. All I know is that the image on the big monitor was set to mirror the laptop monitor. It looks to me as if the color bits got out of order.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly the large monitor is *physically* damage altering how the LCD screen displays data. Yes you could try and recreate something similar.. what have you tried?

Comment: [Photomosh.com](https://photomosh.com/) might do.

Comment: @Scott it is not, the issue lies in the faulty HDMI interface or possibly the graphics driver of the laptop.

Comment: @Scott I would probably try to load the image into an HTML canvas and then try some bit fiddling there, for example instead of having 0xRRGGBB trying 0xRGBRGB so each 4 bits interleaved (and the same with 1 or 2 bits interleaved). But was wondering if there is a software which has a filter that looks similar.

Comment: There is a crack in the screen which is very visible.

Comment: @Scott, do you mean the diagonal line near the top left in the lower picture? You might want to look at [the original](https://www.techboys.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Ubuntu-18.04-LTS-1536x864.jpg.webp). The screen is completely fine. I'm using it right now.

Comment: I think it's not interleaved bits, but just bits in the wrong order -- msb interpreted as lsb and vice-versa. Not sure if the endianness of the color value was changed as well.

Comment: Ahh okay.. I didn't zoom in.. without looking at it larger, all those squiggly lines on the right side *look* like impact cracks.

Comment: You can try this [Image Glitch Tool](https://snorpey.github.io/jpg-glitch/). Not the exact same effect, but similar and quite fun.

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate something similar in Photoshop or GIMP (since I see you are using Linux). It's not a one-click effect, but you could create a colourful texture to overlay any image.

Something like this perhaps. The example is Photoshop, but it could also be achieved in GIMP.

[image]

To create the texture, I basically filled a layer with difference clouds, did a whacky curves adjustment to add lots of vibrant colours, and increased the saturation, then I used the pixelize filter, then the polar co-ordinates filter to make a circular affect, then I repeated the pixelization, with a smaller cell size.

An image is then placed on a layer underneath, and the top layer blending mode changed to "Lighter Color".  GIMP has differently named blending modes so you'll need to experiment.